# How to compare a value against a set of values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
ID    L     a       b
 1  29.13   15.82   5.40
 2  25.23   17.89   7.32
 3  28.10   18.23   7.40
 4  26.39   17.18   7.32
 5  26.08   14.20   5.59
 6  29.62   18.23   6.73
 7  32.96   20.82   9.56
```

`L`, `a`, and `b` are measures to describe Cielab color Standard, and I would like to compare each ID with another set (B1 to B8) of colors using `Delta E` (https://www.viewsonic.com/library/creative-work/what-is-delta-e-and-why-is-it-important-for-color-accuracy/). So, I want my final dataset this way:

```
ID    L     a       b      CS
 1  29.13   15.82   5.40   B1
 2  25.23   17.89   7.32   B2
 3  28.10   18.23   7.40   B3
 4  26.39   17.18   7.32   B4
 5  26.08   14.20   5.59   B7
 6  29.62   18.23   6.73   B8
 7  32.96   20.82   9.56   B1
```

OBS= for CS I used random values, I did not do the calculation. And `CS` is related to the lowest value of `Delta E` among B1 to B8.

To do this I tryed this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# load excel with its path
filename = ("my_file.xlsx")
sh = pd.read_excel(filename) 

#The set of color that I want to compare
b = []
b.extend([[61.3989, 29.7278, 19.1271]]) #B1
b.extend([[50.1579, 44.9554, 28.1963]]) #B2
b.extend([[42.9522, 54.1075, 38.8624]]) #B3
b.extend([[36.6442, 60.9148, 51.0431]]) #B4
b.extend([[31.2828, 54.7112, 45.1422]]) #B5
b.extend([[25.2966, 47.7847, 37.7562]]) #B6
b.extend([[19.3373, 40.9029, 29.2594]]) #B7
b.extend([[13.0943, 33.665, 20.5282]])  #B8

### Delta E formule
DEb = []
for x in b:
    DEb.extend([((x[0]-sh['L'])**2 + (x[1]-sh['a'])**2 + (x[2]-sh['b'])**2)**0.5])
#### This will select the lowest value of the set of values (B1 to B8)
sh['CS'] = str('B') + str(DEb.index(min(DEb)) +1)
print(sh['CS'])
```

Using isolated `ID` values work well, using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = ("my_file.xlsx")
sh = pd.read_excel(filename) 

print  (sh['L'])
def meat_color (Lab):
### Padrão CieLab BBQ
    b = []
    b.extend([[61.3989, 29.7278, 19.1271]])
    b.extend([[50.1579, 44.9554, 28.1963]])
    b.extend([[42.9522, 54.1075, 38.8624]])
    b.extend([[36.6442, 60.9148, 51.0431]])
    b.extend([[31.2828, 54.7112, 45.1422]])
    b.extend([[25.2966, 47.7847, 37.7562]])
    b.extend([[19.3373, 40.9029, 29.2594]])
    b.extend([[13.0943, 33.665, 20.5282]])

    #print('lista: ',b)
    #print(b[0][0])

    ### Criando Lista com valores Delta 1 para grau
    DEb = []
    for x in b:
        DEb.extend([((x[0]-Lab[0])**2 + (x[1]-Lab[1])**2 + (x[2]-Lab[2])**2)**0.5])
    
    print(DEb)
    meat_color = str('B') + str(DEb.index(min(DEb)) +1)
    print('Cor de carne:', meat_color)

    #Valor
    #print('DE: ', nsmallest(1, DEb))
    return meat_color

meat_color([29.13,15.82 ,5.40 ])
```

but when I use the complete dataset I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Análises\labels_nome\Programas\import_openpyxl.py", line 27, in <module>
    sh['cor_carne'] = str('B') + str(DEb.index(min(DEb)) +1)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: For my question you don't need to use the website, was just an additional information. I made the equation. The equation works well with isolated IDs values. But I have problems when I use the complete dataset.

Comment: If you have more information to add, put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about that error message. What research did you do before posting?

Comment: What is obvious to you can be extremely difficult for me.

Comment: If you could go a bit more into detail what the steps are you are trying to do and what you expect to get as result, maybe we can understand what you are doing wrong. `DEb` is a list with 8 `pd.Series`, each with 6 calculated values. What was the goal of `str(DEb.index(min(DEb)) +1)` this part of code?

Comment: @Rabinzel, sorry, my bad, this is very important. `CS` is related to the lowest value of `Delta E` among B1 to B8. Did you undertand?

Comment: There is no lowest value based on Delta E among B1 to B8. b (with B1 to B8) is a list of lists, `DEb` is a list of eight different `pd.Series`. Try `print(DEb)` Is that what you expect `DEb` to look like? That's by the way also where the error comes from. `min(DEb)` searches for the "minimal" value of multiple `pd.Series` which isn't possible. How about you describe by hand step by step for example for the first row of `sh` how you end up with the result `B1`.

Comment: @Rabinzel, for the each value wil generate a list with 8 values, B1 is related the position of the lowest value, I will try explane better.

Comment: Yes, please. Because that doesn't make sense. As I said, Pick an example row and guide us through (written down as edit in your question) with all calculations there are. At the moment, we can't understand the logic of your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't follow the logic of this, but since you said, it works for isolated ID's, here is one way how you could do it. Your whole calculation part will be put in a function which is applied rowwise.

```
def calculations(row):
    DEb = []
    for x in b:
        DEb.append(((x[0]-row['L'])**2 + (x[1]-row['a'])**2 + (x[2]-row['b'])**2)**0.5)
    print(DEb)
    return str('B') + str(DEb.index(min(DEb)) +1)

sh['CS'] = sh.apply(calculations, axis=1)
print(sh)
```

Output:

```
# list "DEb" for each row:
[37.72455543091264, 42.552501750895914, 52.694573561705575, 64.60105855394322, 55.64712432929486, 45.6438460264908, 35.97665651585761, 28.36283016079319]
[39.8463354207134, 42.30550764687737, 51.192838140212544, 62.39492647876108, 53.131496968559055, 42.66215880719118, 32.33658534941499, 23.88686640666791]
[37.12870884450467, 40.413909131139484, 49.976649195899476, 61.64183386540345, 52.587848692640016, 42.459842464262636, 32.690651172162354, 25.21427954017326]
[39.01894378965171, 42.09757495699722, 51.311496985081234, 62.68644847405219, 53.507469367556524, 43.17644561667855, 33.07346117448248, 24.959715758197248]
[40.88753289769389, 45.12964322105815, 54.62904255842308, 66.02922959031099, 56.855984540943446, 46.51032371517102, 36.31458891492509, 27.760843804358682]
[35.99702735588037, 39.960660370669544, 49.97433033918514, 61.927234463441046, 53.00132041864617, 43.06735615393636, 33.576303817722405, 26.490154939712976]
[31.299350415943135, 35.00852717924591, 45.45912848757662, 57.810153972204574, 49.168276298035906, 39.75988480981805, 31.2564743382871, 26.075687387487985]
```

As you can see, the lowest value is always the last value (index 7). So your final result looks like this:

```
   ID      L      a     b  CS
0   1  29.13  15.82  5.40  B8
1   2  25.23  17.89  7.32  B8
2   3  28.10  18.23  7.40  B8
3   4  26.39  17.18  7.32  B8
4   5  26.08  14.20  5.59  B8
5   6  29.62  18.23  6.73  B8
6   7  32.96  20.82  9.56  B8
```

Comment: We got it! haha, yes, it was a bit bumpy to get there. Advice for the future: If your code fails and you provide an example. At least calculate by hand the correct desired result and explain it for a single case. It is the easiest way that people who come here understand what is going on and help you with the code.